# SCCM 2012 Package Exit Code Failure for 3010

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm currently creating a package for SCCM that is wrapped using PowerShell. My package will return 3010 - reboot required when the script is finished. But upon checking the execution history of the machine where I assigned the package, 3010 exit code was recognized as Exit Code Failure. I've been searching many knowledge base site (MSDN, TechNet, etc) but I could not find anything that can enlighten me with this behavior I got for the SCCM package.

So far as I know there is an exit code mapping but from what I saw in SCCM 2012 this feature is only available for applications in SCCM. Is there anyone knows how we will able to make SCCM recognize the exit code of packages in the same way like applications?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not set custom exit code values for Packages. In the properties of the program you can set the 'After running' and have Config Manager control the restart. That should give the user a notification that a restart is required.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thank you for the answer. I also found out the packages does not have the error code mapping like the application models.

Comment: Can you please mark the question as answered so I can earn the points? Thank you.